# Can I pre-define a function in a setTimeout so I don't call it in the brackets

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm kinda new to this incredible language and I am trying to create a function that allows me to slowly reveal how the battle is going. Can I write my function early and then just declare the function in the setTimeout without having to rewrite it because that never seems to work. Here's the not-so-good code I've made:

```
var health=100;
var ehealth=100;
var atk;
var eatk;

function attack(x){
    x=Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
    atk=x;
    ehealth=ehealth-atk
    document.write('Enemy Health:' + '&nbsp; &nbsp;' + ehealth + '&nbsp; &nbsp;')
}

function eattack(x){
    x=Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
    eatk=x;
    health=health-eatk
    document.write('Health:' + '&nbsp; &nbsp;' + health )
}

function dead(){
    if(health<=0){
        document.write('You Lose');
    }else{
        if(ehealth<=0){
            document.write('You Win');
        }
    }
}

function battle(){
    document.write('Enemy Health:' + '&nbsp; &nbsp;' + ehealth + '&nbsp; &nbsp; Health: &nbsp; &nbsp;' + health + '<br/>\n')
    while(health>=0&&ehealth>=0){
        setTimeout(attack(0),400)
        setTimeout(eattack(0),400)
        document.write("<br/>\n");
        dead();
    }
}
```

Help!

Comment: You can include [additional parameters in the call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) like `setTimeout(attack, 400, 0)` but it's not supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it like so:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    attack(0);
}, 400);
```

If you do:

```
setTimeout(attack(0), 400);
```

It will evaluate `attack(0)` immediately, and it will attempt to use the output of `attack(0)` as the callback function (which is not what you want).